# @Around advice throwing errors

Tags: spring, aspectj, spring-aop

I have the following in my aspect. Looks like the execution patter might be the cause. I hope someone could help me finding whats wrong with the following advice.

```
@Around(value = "execution(* com.ss.psystem..*.*(..))")
        public final Object logAround(final ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint)
                throws Throwable {
            Signature signature = joinPoint.getSignature();
            LOGGER.trace("[{}][{}], Entering method...",
                    signature.getDeclaringTypeName(), signature.getName());
            LOGGER.trace("arguments: {}", Arrays.toString(joinPoint.getArgs()));

            Object result = joinPoint.proceed();

            LOGGER.trace("[{}][{}], Exit the method.",
                    signature.getDeclaringTypeName(), signature.getName());
            LOGGER.trace("returned value: [{}]", result);

            return result;
        }
```

Error: Error creating bean with name 'paymentService' defined in class com.ss.psystem.conf.PaymentSystemTestContext: No matching factory method found: factory bean 'paymentSystemTestContext'; factory method 'paymentService()'. Check that a method with the specified name exists and that it is non-static.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than a pointcut pattern issue, this appears to be an error with the way one of your `Spring` beans is defined. You most likely have a bean defined as:

```
<bean class="com.ss.psystem.conf.PaymentSystemTestContext" factory-method="paymentService" />
```

Check that the method `paymentService` is indeed `static`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, actually the problem is not with the pointcut or anything, one of the bean was improperly autowired and hence the issue. It is fixed at my end and I can see the logs.

Thanks for looking at the issue.